# Can suppression lists be updated from Automation Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio, suppressionlist

Our Marketing Cloud hierarchy consists of 170 child business units and a single parent business unit.
Local marketing emails are sent from the 170 child business units.

We track opens and clicks in the mails sent from the child business units and sometimes - based on those interaction - we send subscribers on journeys from the parent business unit.

So, as a SFMC Admin I want to query subscribers on ie. a product journey into a suppression list for my users in my 170 business units to pick as optional suppression lists when sending either a single send email or a multi-step journey.

- The reason for me trying to use suppression lists for this is that I want these to be optional no matter if the local marketeer is using the single send available in Email Studio or using Journey Builder.
- The reason for me using suppression lists and not auto suppression lists is that I want this to be an option for the local marketeer to be in control of.

I know how to query data into data extensions and update these using Automation Studio. But suppression lists are totally new to me.

**How can I use Automation Studio to constantly refresh these suppression lists?**

Thank you

Comment: Maintaining suppression lists is done using query -> data extract -> file transfer -> import file. More of a challenge is how to identify which contacts are in which journeys. There's no generic and reliable way of doing this, currently.

Comment: What macca says. On the topic of Auto Suppressions Configs (ASC). I wanna mention for completeness that the user CAN control which ASC is used, by making the ASC reference a Sender Profile. The user would by their choice of Sender Profile also implicitly decide on which ASC is relevant for this sendout. I acknowledge that is a slightly more complex thing to teach than just having a concrete choice of suppression List, but maybe it is an option.

Comment: Thank you @JonasLamberty - that's a nice to know input :)

Comment: Thank you @Macca - it was easier to do, than I expected. I have some confusion though about the final setup. My suppression list has 4 fields: Email Address, Subscriber Key, Unsubscribe Date, Unsubscribe Reason. The 2 last fields are unexpected and in fact, I don't see my subscriber actually being unsubscribed. If my subscriber isn't actually unsubscribed but just appearing on a suppression list, can I avoid the 2 last field to not create confusion?

Comment: The Reason field doesn't fulfil any particularly significant function. You can leave blank or provide a value for your own reference. As you can see, subscribers on a suppression list aren't unsubscribed. Rather, you use the suppression list to wash your target audience against when you send your emails by manually selecting it.